# How to create XAML with ValidationRole on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, binding

I dinamicaly creare XAML with drag and drop on controls. I create Text Bindind on TextBox, but how to add ValidationRole on Binding.
How to create this:

```
<TextBox.Text>
         <Binding Path="Model.txt1.Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
               <localVal:RequiredValidate />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
         </Binding>
      </TextBox.Text>
```

This is my code:

```
   FrameworkElement SelectedObject = fe_dragged_control;
                    DependencyProperty property =
                        ControlBindingExtensions.GetDependencyPropertyFromName("Text",
                                                                               SelectedObject.GetType());
                    Binding binding = new Binding("Model." + SelectedObject.Name + ".Value");
                    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
                    binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
                    RequiredValidate role = new RequiredValidate();
                    binding.ValidationRules.Add(role);
                    SelectedObject.SetBinding(property, binding);
```

Thank you.